# Precedence of SQL queries in Linq-2-SQL Context

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have a table that holds Key (`LocumID`) - Value (`AvailableDate`) pairs. The table has it's own primer. The key/value cannot be repeated so I added a unique composite constraint on `LocumID & AvailableDate`.

```
OID                  LocumID              AvailableDate           AvailabilityStatusID 
-------------------- -------------------- ----------------------- -------------------- 
1                    1                    2009-03-02 00:00:00     1                    
2                    2                    2009-03-04 00:00:00     1                    
3                    1                    2009-03-05 00:00:00     1                    
4                    1                    2009-03-06 00:00:00     1                    
5                    2                    2009-03-07 00:00:00     1                    
6                    7                    2009-03-09 00:00:00     1                    
7                    1                    2009-03-11 00:00:00     1                    
8                    1                    2009-03-12 00:00:00     2                    
9                    1                    2009-03-14 00:00:00     1                    
10                   1                    2009-03-16 00:00:00     1
```

Now, upon real usage, I find that simply eliminating old value(s) for a LocumID-AvailableDate pair and insert a new one is best approach. However, in Linq-to-SQL, I call `DbContext.SubmitChanges()` in the end and that's where the SQL Server throws an exception complaining that the statement conflicted with the constraint.

Now, if I check my code-lines, I'm deleting pre-existing pair first, creating new and inserting it. Why is the constraint being violated in this transaction?

Also, if I delete the pre-existing pair first, then `SubmitChanges` and then proceed to create a new one, insert it, and `SubmitChanges`... all is well.

However, I lose the benefit of a complete transaction.

Any ideas? Regards.

Comment: Have you set the .Log property on the DataContext so that you can see the offending SQL?  It might help to post that as well.

Comment: And what is the exact error too please?

Comment: I don't know why you are asking those questions. The problem is crystal clear: Linq2Sql performs the insert before the delete.

Comment: Ok: "Linq2Sql performs the insert before the delete". Is that a documented behavior or is it just happening to me. I do understand that the order of query to be executed cannot be determined beforehand nor it is guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SubmitChanges` doesn't guarente the calls to be made in that order. However, instead of relying on linq to sql to make a transaction, simply make one yourself:

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  //first call
  context.SubmitChanges();

  //other work
  context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

linq to sql will first check if it finds a transaction before making one on its own.

Comment: Well, I'm now getting this exception: `Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool.` the scope variable... do I need to flush/close/dispose it... `using` should be handling this automatically.

Comment: I have added a `scope.Complete()` just before the closing bracket of using (my last call)... lets see... no-op: New Exception: `The current TransactionScope is already complete.`... How do I tell DBContext to forget my TransactionScope for further CRUD operations? Seems like it's not letting go of my custom scope...

Comment: Turns out my Context was `static` **DUH**. It was sticking to the transaction as it wasn't being disposed at all. Issues resolved now. Thanks!